# Ajax request failed - mPDF issue

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, mpdf

I have a php file with a AJAX function triggered on `window.onload`.
And a test.php page which creates a PDF file using mPDF, saves the PDF on the server, downloads the PDF in the browser and return a json object to the success handler of the AJAX function.

Or at least that's what it is supposed to do...

If I comment the two `$mpdf->Output` lines, the success handler is triggered and I have what I need in the console.
But if I try to download the PDF, I have an error.

The download used to work (but then I had an error in the AJAX fnction) so I am positive the creation of the PDF is fine.

What am I doing wrong ?

main file

```
window.onload = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.php/",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            "postvar": 1
        },
        success: function(result) {
            console.log("result");
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function(xhr,ajaxOptions,thrownError) {
            let errorMsg = 'Ajax request failed: ' + xhr.responseText;
            console.log(errorMsg);
        }
    });
}
```

test.php

```
$file = "report_".time().".pdf";
$path= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."folder/folder/".$file;
$var = $_POST['postvar'];

$mpdf->Output($path,'F'); // Never worked
$mpdf->Output('report.pdf','D'); // Download used to work...

$result = array('generatedPDF' => $file,'path' => $path, 'test' => $var);
echo json_encode($result);
```

Error message

```
Ajax request failed: %PDF-1.4
%����
3 0 obj
<</Type /Page
/Parent 1 0 R
...
```

The error message is much longer !

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Downloading a file and sending JSON **in the same response** won't work as far as I know

Comment: _“The error message is much longer !”_ - most of that is the actual binary PDF data. I read recently somewhere that the `F` method apparently tries to store the file, _and_ outputs its content at the same time (despite the documentation indicating otherwise.) Try to wrap that into an output buffer and discard the contents afterwards, or use the `S` mode, that will return the document as a string, so that you can then store it into a file yourself using file_put_contents.